# Cart page address aren't show in checkout page billing details area. But Ship to a different address area show the correct one

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How to forcefully auto selected Bulling details field like cart page address filed information. Ship to a different address area show the right one but Bulling details area isn't.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_state', 'mehedi_change_default_checkout_state' );
function mehedi_change_default_checkout_state() {
    $state = WC()->customer->get_shipping_state();
    return $state; // state code
}
```